# Angular - is there a way to get the cell id on click

Tags: angular, mat-table, angular-material-7

I would like to click on any cell of my mat-table and get the row and column of my cell.

I know that with this code I get the clicked row, but I can't figure out how to get the correspondent column.id

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="anyfunction(row.id)"></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the (click) event in the `<td>` element instead of `<tr>`

Comment: thank you, do I have to do this for every single column or is there a way to write this code simplified?

Comment: i think you have to add it for every single column. Maybe you can use a `*ngFor`